# Hessian and quadratic form

Tags: multivariable-calculus, quadratic-forms, hessian-matrix

I can't understand what my professor meant in our Calc III book. In a demostration, he wrote something like "we are going to refer to the hessian ($Hf_{P}$) and its associated quadratic form ($Q_{P}(V)=\frac{1}{2}\langle Hf_{P}V,V \rangle$) indistinctly.".
As far as I know, in a quadratic form ($Q(X)=\langle XA,X \rangle$), $A=a_{ii}$ is given by $$a_{ij} =
\begin{cases}
    a_{ii}, &         \text{if } i=j,\\
    \frac{a_{ij}+a_{ji}}{2}, &         \text{if } i\neq j.
\end{cases}$$
Then, how is it possible to refer to them indistinctly?

Comment: Your characterization of a quadratic form is nigh tautological. It basically says that $a_{ij}=a_{ij}$.

Comment: Just in case that $i=j$, if $i \neq j$ then $a_{ij} \neq a_{ji}$. Am I right?

Comment: Not really.  You’ve got $a_{ij}$ on both sides of the equation, so what you’ve written is effectively $a_{ij}=a_{ji}$, i.e., that $A$ is symmetric, which is _not_ necessary for a quadratic form.

Comment: What the professor means is simply that he’s not going to bother taking care to distinguish the matrix $H$ from its associated quadratic form—they’ll be used interchangeably.

Answer (score 1):

Given the quadratic form $Q,$ and column vector $X,$ the matrix $H$ is 
$$ h_{ij} = \frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}  $$
and the form is then
$$ Q(X) = \frac{1}{2}  X^T H X  $$

For example,  take form
$$ x^2 + 2 y^2 + 3 z^2 + 4 yz + 5 zx + 6xy \; , \; $$
the Hessian matrix is
$$
H =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
2 & 6 & 5\\
6 & 4 & 4 \\
5 & 4 & 6
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. I mean, it wouldn't be like that just if the hessian were $HQ_{P}$?
Also, why is written as $Q_{P}(V)= \langle Hf_{P}V,V \rangle$ and not as $Q_{P}(V)= \langle V^{T}Hf_{P},V \rangle$?

Comment: @JohannCarlFriedrichPlanck  if you have column vectors $X,Y$ the inner product is the dot product, $\langle X,Y \rangle = X \cdot Y= X^T Y = Y^T X\; , \;$ That is at a specific point,

Comment: Thanks. Still without undersanding why the matrix H is $h_{ij}=\frac{\partial^2 Q}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}$ instead of $h_{ij}=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}$.

Comment: same thing. I suspect you are doing multivariable Taylor Series